# How to get CLOB data in Dart

Tags: dart, blob, clob

I have to get CLOB data using Dart from db stored html data in it. How can I get it? Can anyone help me or give me some advices ?

Comment: Did you try something on you own so far?

Comment: I solved the problem. I used NVARCHAR.

Comment: Can you post your solution and accept it? Just to keep it for people that might need it in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Sqflite local DB(cuz I'm developing offline app) and stored CLOB as'a NVARCHAR.